# Why Backbone Collection 'sort' event and the sorting action itself are not triggered / done under the same conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, events, backbone.js

I have a Backbone.Collection -> Backgrid related bug. The behaviour is that after a collection is being fetched, the backgrid table is rendered twice.

I have investigated this, and found out that is related to the 'sort' event being called on Backbone.Collection.

By default, Backgrid is listening to the following event

```
this.listenTo(collection, "add", this.insertRow);
this.listenTo(collection, "remove", this.removeRow);
this.listenTo(collection, "sort", this.refresh);
this.listenTo(collection, "reset", this.refresh);
this.listenTo(collection, "backgrid:sort", this.sort);
this.listenTo(collection, "backgrid:edited", this.moveToNextCell);
```

We are not doing any Front-end sorting with our collection so I was wondering why the 'sort' event was being called.

I have investigated this more on the Backbone.Collection implementation and found the following :

After fetch, the 'set' method is being called on the collection, which, among other things, contains the following block of code

```
// Silently sort the collection if appropriate.
  if (sort) this.sort({silent: true});

  // Unless silenced, it's time to fire all appropriate add/sort events.
  if (!options.silent) {
    var addOpts = at != null ? _.clone(options) : options;
    for (var i = 0; i < toAdd.length; i++) {
      if (at != null) addOpts.index = at + i;
      (model = toAdd[i]).trigger('add', model, this, addOpts);
    }
    if (sort || orderChanged) this.trigger('sort', this, options);
    if (toAdd.length || toRemove.length) this.trigger('update', this, options);
  }
```

Here we can see that the sorting action itself, is dependent on 'sort' variable. Which is fine, in my case, that is a false, so is not doing any sorting at all.

However, the 'sort' event itself, is being called based either on 'sort' or 'orderChanged' being true.

The tricky part is that 'orderChanged' is true even for the first fetch which is causing for this event to be triggered.

**As a solution**, I just prevented Backbone from listening to this event (We don't do any UI sorting so that's acceptable for us) but I was wondering why the sorting action and sort event are not done/triggered under the same conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know backgrid and what is your current implementation but I think it may come from the fact that backgrid is maybe using binding a comparator to the collection.

Then "You don't need to call this under normal circumstances, as a collection with a comparator will sort itself whenever a model is added. "

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sort

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense. For the sorting itself. Actually, if you don't have a comparator, that 'sort' variable is going to be undefined, so no sorting is done. However, the 'sort' event is still being called because of that 'orderChanged' variable which at least for the first fetch, is always true because it checks an empty collection (initial state) against an array of freshly fetched models